# Fetch Date from database that is shipped with android app

Tags: android, sql, database, sqlite

I am following this tutorial http://mobisys.in/blog/2012/01/tutorial-using-database-in-android-applications/ to have an external database with my android app.

I am not able to apply where clause while fetching the data from the database.
This is what I have done so far.

```
c=myDbHelper.query("level1", null, "_id=2", null, null,null, null);
    if(c.moveToFirst())
   {
       do {

        Toast.makeText(Level1.this,
                   "_id: " + c.getString(0) + "\n" +
                   "name: " + c.getString(1) + "\n" 
                   ,
                   Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

       } while (c.moveToNext());
   }
```

The databaseHelper class

```
public Cursor query(String table,String[] columns, String selection,String[] selectionArgs,String groupBy,String having,String orderBy){
    return myDataBase.query("level1", null, "_id", null, null, null, null);


}
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You pass `"_id=2"` as `selection`  when calling `myDbHelper.query`. But in your DB Helper `query` method, `selection` is never used (same goes for other parameters).

You probably want to change `query` to something like:

```java
public Cursor query(String table, String[] columns, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String groupBy, String having, String orderBy){
    // double check parameters I did type that here (no IDE)
    return myDataBase.query(table, columns, selection, selectionArgs, groupBy, having, orderBy);
}
```

See also, [the documentation of `SQLiteDatabase`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#query(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String))

Comment: Thank you, it worked. I should have checked the documentation it just slipped off my mind. Anyways thank you.